# In Ansible, how do I check if a particular version of MySQL is installed?

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible task that wraps a rather complex shell script that someone else maintains. This shell script installs a heavily customized web stack, where many of the components are compiled from source.

Every so often, the shell script updates various components to newer versions. When this happens, I want my Ansible template tasks that manage the conf files for those services to fail, so that I can manually review what changed.

**Using Ansible, how do I check the installed version of something and register that as a variable that I can use in a later task?**

Example: MariaDB is compiled from source, so I want to create an Ansible variable equal to the output of `mysql --version`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use ansible command and register it output to variable

```
tasks:
   - command: mysql --version
     name: ls
     register: mysql_version
   - command: service mysql stop
     when: mysql_version.stdout_lines == 'mysql ver 14.14'
```

please see this link for more information http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#id18

Answer (score 2):

## Update for Ansible 2.9+

Ansible version 2.9 introduced the mysql_info module [(official docs)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/mysql_info_module.html) which returns the version of MySQL.

```
tasks:
  - name: Get MySQL version with non-default credentials
    mysql_info:
      login_user: mysuperuser
      login_password: mysuperpass
      filter: version
    register: _mysql_version
```

The `_mysql_version` variable will contain something like the following:

```
{
    "_mysql_version": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "version": {
            "major": 8,
            "minor": 0,
            "release": 23
        }
}
```

Thus the version is referenced with `_mysql_version.version` like so:

```
tasks:
    - name: shutdown the server when version less than 8
    - service:
        name: mysql
        state: stopped
      when: _mysql_version.version.major < 8
```

**Note:** After Ansible 2.9, the `mysql_info` module is now part of the MySQL community collection and is thus referenced with `community.mysql.mysql_info`.